# Entity Framework foriegn key to existing table column

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the following table in my database

Company

- resourceId (uniqueidentifier)
- name (nvarchar(50))

I have the following User entity in my application

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{

    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String Surname { get; set; }
    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }

}
```

and a configuration class

```
public class ApplicationUserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser>
{

    public ApplicationUserMap()
    {



    }

}
```

Using fluentapi how can I map a foriegn key from CompanyId in Application user to my existing table resourceid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that if `Company` is not included in your model.

You can only create the relationship in the DB using an standard T-SQL sentence, in the DB initialization (`Seed()`) or in a customized migration (if you're using migrations).

The command would loook like this:

```
alter table ApplicationUser
add constraint App_Company_FK FOREIGN KEY (CompanyId) references Company(CompanyId)
```

To run it in the `Seed` method, override the inhertied `Seed()` method, and [use any of the overloads of Database.ExecuteSqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database%28v=vs.113%29.aspx):

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand( ... );
```